# How to replicate values in informatica?

Tags: informatica

```
var1=length(some port)
```

I want to do `replicate('0',var1)` in expression transformation logic in informatica.

Comment: Ok... had to lookup replicate function for this one... if my understanding is right, you want to replace a field of x length with an equally lengthed field of 0's

Comment: Yes you got it correct

Answer (score 1):

Use Informatica REPLACECHR() function (see http://forgetcode.com/Informatica/1816-REPLACECHR-Replace-characters-in-a-string-with-some-other-character-or-remove-them)

For a number field you could use TO_CHAR to convert it to a string and then use the resulting variable (lets call it v_out) to run the replace on i.e. REPLACECHR(1, v_out,'123456789', '0')

Comment: It will only replace that number one time with a 0.But we need to append that much zeros.

Comment: It replaces all occurrences, not just the first occurrence... please if you can share one source input value, one resultant output field (where only one occurrence is replaced) and the exact expression you defined so I can help you troubleshoot